# Не получаются некоторые ячейки при использовании Apache POI - Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Всем привет. При разработке программы с использованием Apache POI возникла проблема. После прочтения файла в некоторых строках Excel таблицы пропадают некоторые ячейки. Знает ли кто-нибудь из-за чего это может возникать и как это исправить? Использую Apache POI версии 3.17.
[image: Часть таблицы из которой копируются данные]

[image: Итератор, в котором видно, что ячейки из колонок 5-7 пропали]

Comment: Они не пропадают, там как я понимаю merge клеток сделан и поэтому вам показывает что ячейка пуста, посмотрите данные в следующей  строке, колонке